# Reprompting if input is invalid in c++

Tags: c++, loops

I know this is probably a pretty basic question, but I'm stumped. I'm trying to prompt the user to enter 1, 2, 3, or 4. And, if they don't enter a valid choice, to ask them again. But whenever I execute the program and enter an invalid result, it just loops without stopping for user input, printing the first cout line over and over again. How can I fix this? Is calling the function from within itself a bad idea? Do I need to clear the cin somehow?

```
int hallwayask()
{
    int input;
    cout << "1: Door 1 \n2: Door 2 \n3: Door 3 \n4: Door 4\n";
    cin >> input;
    if (cin.good())
    {
        switch(input)
        {
            case 1:
                room1();
                break;
            case 2:
                room2();
                break;
            case 3:
                room3();
                break;
            case 4:
                room4();
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Please enter a valid number." << endl;
                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        hallwayask();
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: `hallwayask` promises to return an `int` but doesn't. This can lead to a buggy program.

Comment: Side note: consider using a loop here rather than recursion.

Comment: Might as well drop this here, too: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear .

Comment: Always the easier and correct way to do this task is 1) read the input as a string, 2) check if the string matches expectations 3) convert the string to an integer. This is the approach that works. As an example of why your approach doesn't work try the input "4b", this will be read as the integer 4 and it will pass all your tests. But it's not correct input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that once `cin` fails, you are not `clear()`'ing the stream's error state, so `operator>>` keeps failing and `good()` keeps returning `false`, so you get stuck in an endless loop.

You need to valid the user's input before you use it, and clear the input when it is not valid so you don't keep re-reading it.

Also, you should be using an iterative loop instead of a recursive loop.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <limits>

int hallwayask()
{
    int input;
    cout << "1: Door 1 \n2: Door 2 \n3: Door 3 \n4: Door 4\n";
    do
    {
        if (!(cin >> input))
        {
            cout << "Invalid input! Please enter an integer only." << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            continue;
        }

        if ((input >= 1) && (input <= 4))
            break;

        cout << "Please enter a valid number 1-4." << endl;
    }
    while (true);

    switch (input)
    {
        case 1:
            room1();
            break;
        case 2:
            room2();
            break;
        case 3:
            room3();
            break;
        case 4:
            room4();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this snippet. It's self explanatory, plus you don't have to call that function again and again, making the logic easier and the program faster.

```cpp
int hallwayask()
{
    int input;

//Write the "do{" here if you wish these
//options to be shown again and again when
//user gives invalid input

    cout << "1: Door 1 \n2: Door 2 \n3: Door 3 \n4: Door 4\n";

    do
    { //this is the "do{" I referred to earlier
        cin >> input;

        switch (input)
        {

            case 1:
                room1();
                break;

            case 2:
                room2();
                break;

            case 3:
                room3();
                break;

            case 4:
                room4();
                break;

            default:
                cout << "Please enter a valid number: " << endl;
                break;
        }
    } while ((input != 1) && (input != 2) && (input != 3) && (input != 4));

    return (input); //the correct input is returned to the calling function

}
```

About your question - No, calling the same function from itself (what we call as a 'Recursive call') isn't bad as long as you know that the call chain will terminate at a point. A very common example is a recursive algorithm to find factorial of an integer. We don't use Recursive functions where an end-point may not be reached, such as in this case; what if the user continues to give wrong inputs? You'll just fill up your stack, and there'd be a crash if the memory do gets full. (Because each recursive function call pushes the current instance of the function on a stack)

Comment: Implementing factorial with recursion recursion uses way too much space and is very slow. It’s much simpler and much more efficient to write it as a loop. Recursion can be a powerful tool for analyzing algorithms and for thinking about computability, but is is **extremely rare** in real-world code. There is (almost) always a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int hallwayask();

int main()
{
    hallwayask();

}

int hallwayask()
{
    int input;
    bool flag = true;
    while (flag)
    {
        cout << "1: Door 1 \n2: Door 2 \n3: Door 3 \n4: Door 4\n";
        cin >> input;
        if (cin.good())
        {
            switch(input)
            {
                case 1:
                    cout << room1();
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cout << room2();
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cout << room3();
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    cout << room4();
                    flag = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    cout << "Please enter a valid number." << endl;
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid input, enter an int" << endl;
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(INT8_MAX, '\n');
        }
    }
}
```

I am setting a bool flag to true and while this is true it will go on forever but as soon as the user inputs the right number (1-2-3-4) I am setting the flag to false, so it will stop.

Think of it this way: while true do this block of code, if false stop.
So the while goes on forever if true but as soon as I input 1-2-3-4 I am stopping the while loop.

I am sure there are other ways of doing it; I always relied on flag true/false for this, but other options available.